# Log4j2.19.0 RollingFileAppender Programatically in java

Tags: java, log4j2, rollingfileappender

How to create `RollingFileAppender` programmatically in Java?

In log4j1 this works:

```java
Logger rootLogg;
RollingFileAppender appendFile;
rootLogg = LogManager.getRootLogger();
appendFile = (RollingFileAppender)rootLogg.getAppender("appendFile");
```

but in log4j 2.19.0 it doesn't.

I want `RollingFileAppender` programatically for log4j2.19.0 in Java.

All properties of appender are defined in *log4j2.properties* file.

```
URL url = null;
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
if (propertiesFile !=null)
    url = EMSLogger.class.getClassLoader().getResource("log4j2.properties");
if (url != null) {
    try {
        URI uri =new URI(url.toString());
        context.setConfigLocation(uri);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have been through many answers but could not find solution for my problem.
I'm expecting working code.